# JSON with multi tasking

Tags: java, c++, json, qt, websocket

I am new to Qt C++ development. I have a processor which will control the Hardware. From server (Java) I will send the instructions to that Hardware. According to that particular instruction, it is going to perform. This is the general idea of my project.

Basic control instructions were written on board. Now What I want and What is the problem I am going to describe that? Sorry for my poor English.

I am going to send the JSON string from the server. For example

```
working|pq|0|1
```

From web socket I will receive the string

```
else if(message.contains("working")) { 
         emit OnMsgRecievedConnect("connect"); 
         workingpq = message;
         qDebug() << workingpq;
}
```

Now I have received a string from the server. I have taken that string into another thread for giving instruction to Hardware.

```
workingvaluepq = EchoClient::workingpq ;
qDebug() << "End pq value Received from server :" << workingvaluepq ;

QStringList pq = workingvaluepq.split("|");

int pqSize = pq.size(); // get the pq list size;
qDebug() << "End pq size :" << pqSize;

if(pqSize == 5){
     p = pq[3];
     q = pq[4];
  }

int pInt = p.toInt(&ok);
int qInt = q.toInt(&ok);

if(!ok && pqSize == 5){
    pend = pInt;
}

if(!ok && pqSize == 5){
    qend = qInt;
}

    pend = pInt;
    qend = qInt;

if(pqSize == 1 ){
    pend = jread->endvaluep;
    qend = jread->endvalueq;
}

while(true)
{      (All other stuff here)

   if(pqSize == 5){
            if (pend == pstart && qend == qstart)
            {
                Jsonendflag = 1;
            }
        }

   if(pqSize == 1){
            if (pend == pstart && qend == qstart)
            {
                Rightstopflag = 1;
            }
        }
```

So when this point (whatever we fixed) reached the particular task, finally it will get stop. Maybe above code have some experienced issue. So a person can help me to improve the code. One more question, This is only one task, I have tried.

Note: pstart, qstart, pend, qend these things defined in the onboard JSON file. Just I will read and execute so reading executing is not a big deal
If I receive the multiple string (task) from server machine have to complete the task one by one. For example, will receive the string like given below

```
working|xy|2|3*working1|xy|8|7*working3|xy|12|15*working4|xy|17|20
```

Above string have a four different task, I will receive in same time, now I want to split and complete the task one by one continuously. I hope here so many experienced people can help and solve this issue.

Comment: It is Qt, not QT, QT is for Quick Time.

Comment: Thanks for your kind information. I have modified according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you split using *, use a loop to process your tasks one by one.

```
const QStringList taskList = QString("working|xy|2|3*working1|xy|8|7*working3|xy|12|15*working4|xy|17|20").split('*');

    for (const QString& task : taskList)
    {
        auto params = task.split('|');
        /* Perform 1 task */
       // ...
    }

/* Report back to server */
// ...
```

The code above uses a C++ ranged-for-loop.

You can do the same using an older for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < taskList.count(); ++i)
{
    auto params = taskList[i].split('|');
    /* Perform 1 task */
   // ...
}
```

Comment: How can I take the particular task? If totally 5 functions are there then how to complete each and every task one by one?

Comment: You can save that into array, then complete one by one task `QStringList ab = taskList[0].split("|");`

Comment: Ya I have created the array, then stored first value. Then checking          `int aInt = a.toInt(&ok);` That is working fine.